# reassign string values in a list in a series

Tags: python, pandas, list, series

I am trying to reassign the values of the list that is in the series with the new stemmed string values. However, I cant figure out how to do that. Currently I am making a new list and appending the newly stemmed words, but that just puts all of words from all the list together in the list `ns`. Where I want to just update the current list with the newly stemmed items.

```
words = data.String.apply(lambda x: word_tokenize(x))
ns =[]
#print(words)
for i in words:
    for j in i:
        ns.append(ps.stem(j))
```

For example, `words`=

```
0    [I, loved, dogs, because, they, are, cute, and...
1    [my, dog, is, looking, at, me, weird, maybe, c...
2    [I, think, I, look, like, a, cupacake, one, wi...
3    [do, you, want, to, be, a, snowman, no, thanks...
4    [hey, do, you, know, what, time, it, is, cooking,...
5     [dogs, are, so, awesome, dogs, are, so, awesome]
```

after putting it through the for loop to stem the words, `words` should be like this:

```
    0    [I, love, dog, becaus, they, are, cute, and...
    1    [my, dog, is, look, at, me, weird, maybe, c...
    2    [I, think, I, look, like, a, cupacake, one, wi...
    3    [do, you, want, to, be, a, snowman, no, thank...
    4    [hey, do, you, know, what, time, it, is, cook,...
    5     [dog, are, so, awesome, dog, are, so, awesome]
```

In:

```
print(type(words))
print(type(words[1]))
print(type(words[1][1]))
```

Out:

```
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
<class 'list'>
<class 'str'>
```

Any thoughts?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use list comprehension with `ps.stem` function:

```
print (data)
                                    String
0   I loved dogs because they are cute and
1      my dog is looking at me weird maybe
2       I think I look like a cupacake one
3    do you want to be a snowman no thanks
4  hey do you know what time it is cooking
5  dogs are so awesome dogs are so awesome
```

---

```
from nltk.stem.snowball import SnowballStemmer
from nltk import word_tokenize
ps = SnowballStemmer("english")

words = data.String.apply(lambda x: [ps.stem(y) for y in word_tokenize(x)])
print (words)
0      [i, love, dog, becaus, they, are, cute, and]
1          [my, dog, is, look, at, me, weird, mayb]
2        [i, think, i, look, like, a, cupacak, one]
3    [do, you, want, to, be, a, snowman, no, thank]
4    [hey, do, you, know, what, time, it, is, cook]
5      [dog, are, so, awesom, dog, are, so, awesom]
Name: String, dtype: object
```

If need reasign to same column:

```
data.String = data.String.apply(lambda x: [ps.stem(y) for y in word_tokenize(x)])
print (data)
                                           String
0    [i, love, dog, becaus, they, are, cute, and]
1        [my, dog, is, look, at, me, weird, mayb]
2      [i, think, i, look, like, a, cupacak, one]
3  [do, you, want, to, be, a, snowman, no, thank]
4  [hey, do, you, know, what, time, it, is, cook]
5    [dog, are, so, awesom, dog, are, so, awesom]
```

Or to new column:

```
data['Stem'] = data.String.apply(lambda x: [ps.stem(y) for y in word_tokenize(x)])
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep the two for loops you would need to use the indices to look through. In python when you use `for i in lst`. `i` is equal to each element in the list. To change the value in a list you would need the index.

change your loops to use the indices instead:

```
for i in range(len(words)):
    for j in range(len(words[i])):
       words[i][j] = "something new"
```

this will allow you to change the value in the spot `[i][j]` in the array.